# Query Rule Question - How to drop unmatched SearchTerms not present in Result Source

Tags: search, query-rule

Is it possible to drop any unmatched search terms from your query AFTER the query has been issued?

For example, user issues following query: "massive email mishap."  I need "massive" and "mishap" to be dropped from this query, because ......(and here is the important part)......they are words which are not present in the result source that this query is searching (which is a wiki library where all words are indexed, leading me to believe that this request may be possible).

Issuing above query breaks the query, resulting in "nothing here matches your search." However, issuing a query such as: "email mishap" works perfect because of the query rule I have in effect. Query rule is as follows, Query Contains Action Term.  Action term is "email," query is changed to "{subject Terms}=email."

Is it possible to create a rule that will drop any unmatched term?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the terms are that you want to remove, you could create a Query Rule "Contains Action". Then for your query use `{actionTerms}`, or `Title:{actionTerms}`. This will omit the unmatched terms. The challenge is knowing the terms in advance.

Comment: Dang.  I was hoping for a way to write a query along the lines of: {searchboxquery} -{searchTerms}

Comment: thanks @Matthew for again helping me with my query rule issues.  I am trying to find a solution that won't need an explicit declaration in advance though.  For the above query I was hoping that the searchTerms would be subtracted from the searchboxquery, but I guess that isn't how to make this happen.

Comment: That's what the Action Terms query rule does. The matched terms become the ActionTerms. If you perform a query with `-{searchTerms} it will eliminate results that contain the searchTerms. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Double Dang!!.  Can I do: {actionTerm} -{subjectTerms} instead? If this article is correct, it looks as if any word/phrase that is not defined as an {actionTerm} becomes a {subjectTerm} in a query.  See: http://sharepointfordeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-search-bound-variables.html